# Is Gauss curvature a Morse function?

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

Given a Gauss map $\nu: M \rightarrow S^k$ of a orientable, compact manifold, we define the shape operator $S_p = -d \nu: T_p M \rightarrow T_{\nu(p)} S^k$ to be the negative differential. Define the Gauss curvature $K: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $K(p) = det(S_p)$.

My question is whether $K$ is a Morse function. We say a function on a manifold $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Morse if every critical point is nondegenerate.

EDIT: Assume that $M$ is not a surface of constant Gauss curvature.

My motivation for asking this question: I am an undergrad studying homological filtrations of a manifold by its Gauss curvature. I know a bit of Morse theory and was hoping to be able to pull out a result or two from Morse theory in my project.

Comment: What if $M$ is $S^k$ itself, with its usual metric?  The Gauss curvature is constant, and therefore not a morse function (unless $k=0$).

Comment: @AndreasBlass This is a good example. Thank you for providing it. The solution is not the most satisfying unfortunately. Do you have any idea what to expect if we ban the monster of constant Gauss curvature? This is not that ridiculous of a monster-banning. For example, the Four Vertex Theorem states that a simple closed curve other than a circle must have at least four vertexes. (A vertex is a critical point wrt curvature).

Comment: You can try $ \#^{n} \! \left( \mathbb{T}^{2} \right) $.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore I am assuming your notation means that you are taking $n$ tori, removing at least one open disk in each, then gluing them together along the boundaries of those disks

Comment: You can bend a sphere somewhere so that its curvature is not constant any more but there are pieces with constant curvature. And I guess given any smooth function on a manifold, as long as the function satisfies some global restrictions (e.g. applied by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem), you can find a metric that gives the desired Gauss curvature. That is, Gauss curvature can be any smooth function.

Comment: @XipanXiao: That is quite doubtful.(Even if you find such a metric, it is also not obvious that it can be realized as an induced metric to $\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: @MattR: Yes, Matt. That’s what I meant — the connected sum of $ n $ tori.

Comment: @Matt: Hi Matt. Given the well-known parametrization
$$
(x,y,z) = ([c + a \cos(v)] \cos(u),[c + a \cos(v)] \sin(u),a \sin(v)), \quad
(u,v) \in \Bbb{R}^{2}
$$
of $ \Bbb{T}^{2} $, the Gaussian curvature is given by
$$
K(u,v) = \frac{\cos(v)}{a [c + a \cos(v)]}, \quad (u,v) \in \Bbb{R}^{2},
$$
which is certainly non-constant. I haven’t worked out the details yet, but I think that it follows from this that every critical point of $ K $ is degenerate, and so $ K $ is not a Morse function.

Comment: My bet would be (haven't thought much about this...) that such a thing might be generic. That is an open and dense set of metrics will give you a Morse functions as curvatures. Such things will not have any symmetries...

Comment: @Thomas: Hi Thomas. When you say ‘generic’, are you implicitly assuming the $ C^{\infty} $-topology on the space of Riemannian metrics?

Comment: @ThomasRot You comment interests me. If you could elaborate, I would be appreciative. I believe you may be referring to a result that the set of Morse functions is dense in $\mathcal{C}(M, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @Matt: Hi Matt. I’ve explained a little about what Thomas means in my pseudo-answer below. He isn’t referring to the set of Morse functions being dense in $ C(M,\Bbb{R}) $. He’s talking about the set of Riemannian metrics on an oriented and compact smooth manifold, equipped with a Fréchet-manifold structure.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore The Hessian of the Gauss curvature of the torus is everywhere singular. Thus, it is not Morse. I think more generally that this is also true for any surface of revolution.

Comment: @Matt: Yep! Hence, we’ve ruled out those classes of Riemannian manifolds, even though they have non-constant Gaussian curvature.

Comment: @MattR: I think Berrick Fillmore beat me to an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.

First a couple of remarks on set-up: If an oriented $n$-manifold $M$ is smoothly embedded in some Euclidean space $E^{N}$, then the Gauss map usually refers to the map sending a point $p$ of $M$ to the oriented vector subspace parallel to $T_{p}M \subset E^{N}$, viewed as an element of the Grassmannian of oriented $n$-planes in $E^{N}$; the Grassmannian has dimension $n(N - n)$, so the determinant is defined if and only if $n(N - n) = n$ (i.e., $N = n + 1$), if and only if $M$ is a hypersurface. In this event, the Gauss map can be viewed as taking values in the sphere $S^{n}$ by identifying the oriented hyperplane $T_{p}M \subset E^{n+1}$ with the unit normal compatible with a fixed orientation of $E^{n+1}$.

For simplicity, let's assume $M$ is an oriented surface smoothly embedded in $E^{3}$.

Results of Kazdan and Warner give conditions for a function on a surface to be the Gaussian curvature of some Riemannian metric. Their [1971 survey article](http://www.ams.org/bull/1971-77-05/S0002-9904-1971-12818-5/S0002-9904-1971-12818-5.pdf) in the Bulletin of the AMS is a readable introduction for the compact, orientable case, and their [1975 paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970993) in the *Annals of Mathematics* contains sharpened results. (The second link may require JSTOR registration, but one statement of interest is on the first page. The full article can be found [here](http://www.kfki.hu/~iracz/sgimp/cikkek/KazdanWarner.pdf).)

The closing section of their 1975 paper notes, "[Nirenberg's solution of the Weyl embedding problem, *Communications in Pure and Applied Mathematics* **6** (1953) 337-394, implies that] given any smooth strictly positive function $K$ on $S^{2}$, there is a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ of $S^{2}$, a compact, strictly convex surface $\Sigma$ in $E^{3}$, and a conformal diffeomorphism $\psi:\Sigma \to S^{2}$ such that $K \circ \varphi \circ \psi$ is the Gaussian curvature of $\Sigma$."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will have a look at these. I am also interested in what persistence modules can be realized as sublevelset persistence of Gauss curvature on a manifold. These papers are the sort of thing I am thinking about

Comment: @user86418 The Kazdan Warner paper guarantees that there is always a Morse function that is the Gauss curvature for some metric on any compact, connected surface. But it does not seem to guarantee that there is an embedding of the surface in $R^3$ except in the case of positive Euler characteristic. What about the other cases? Also the statement for positive Euler class seems to complicated for the question. The Gauss curvature is just the determinant off the Gauss map and so mustn't equal K?

Comment: @JoeS: As mentioned, this isn't a complete answer. :) Naively I'd expect embeddability to be a subtle issue. If I understand your question about the sphere: $K$ is a _specified_ smooth, positive function on the set of unit vectors in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$. K-W's claim is there's a smooth, convex surface $\Sigma$ whose Gaussian curvature $\kappa$ "is" $K$ _up to conformal change of the metric and a global change of coordinates_. (If $K$ is Morse, then so is $\kappa$, since diffeomorphisms preserve non-degeneracy of critical points.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt, but one that is far from complete if one decides to pursue this problem even further.

---

As Dr. Andreas Blass has pointed out, the $ n $-spheres $ \Bbb{S}^{n} $, equipped with the standard differential structures and metrics, have constant positive Gaussian curvatures, so these curvatures cannot be Morse functions.

The OP was then edited so as to exclude oriented and compact Riemannian manifolds that have a constant Gaussian curvature. Even so, the assertion is not true, as we now show.

Consider the well-known smooth embedding $ \eta $ of the torus $ \Bbb{T}^{2} = \Bbb{S}^{1} \times \Bbb{S}^{1} $ into $ \Bbb{R}^{3} $ defined by
$$
\eta \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\left\{ \begin{matrix}
\Bbb{S}^{1} \times \Bbb{S}^{1} & \to & \Bbb{R}^{3} \\
(u,v) & \mapsto & ([c + a \cos(v)] \cos(u),[c + a \cos(v)] \sin(u),a \sin(v))
\end{matrix} \right\}.
$$
Via this embedding, $ \Bbb{T}^{2} $ inherits a metric from $ \Bbb{R}^{3} $ whose Gaussian curvature is given by
$$
\forall (u,v) \in \Bbb{S}^{1} \times \Bbb{S}^{1}: \quad
K(u,v) = \frac{\cos(v)}{a [c + a \cos(v)]}.
$$
This is certainly non-zero. Next, observe that
$$
\forall (u,v) \in \Bbb{S}^{1} \times \Bbb{S}^{1}: \quad
  {\nabla K}(u,v)
= \left( 0,- \frac{a c \sin(v)}{a^{2} [c + a \cos(v)]^{2}} \right).
$$
Hence, the set of critical points is $ \Bbb{S}^{1} \times \{ 0,\pi \} $. Each critical point is then degenerate because the Hessian of $ K $ can easily be shown to have three $ 0 $ entries (due to the lack of a dependence on $ u $) and is therefore singular.

---

Let $ M $ be an oriented and compact smooth manifold. The space $ \text{Met}(M) $ of Riemannian metrics on $ M $ can be equipped with the $ C^{\infty} $-topology, which turns it into a Fréchet manifold.

As Thomas as mentioned, the set of metrics whose Gaussian curvature is a Morse function may be generic (i.e., open and dense) in $ \text{Met}(M) $. Of course, this is pure speculation at the present moment.